# Group by and inner join: how to select joined without a "max" trick

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

Here is a simple query:

```
SELECT orders.id, customers.name, COUNT(order_product.id)
FROM orders
INNER JOIN order_product ON orders.id = order_product.order_id
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
GROUP BY orders.id;
```

In other words, I want:

- The ID of an order.
- The number of products (count) in each order.
- The customer name of the order.

The problem is about selecting `customers.name`. I cannot select it directly because it's not in aggregate function nor group by. But **there is only one**, so I d'ont know why I have to aggregate it. I can do a trick like this to select its name:

```
SELECT MAX(customers.name)
```

But I think it's dirty, because I don't want the "max name of a customer for an order" but "the name of the customer for an order". **What is the elegant way to do such a thing?**

Hope it's clear and not a duplicate.

***EDIT***: an order have only one customer identified by `orders.customer_id`. That's why I asking why I have to do such a trick.

Comment: an order have only one customer ?!?

Comment: Yes. I edit my question.

Comment: And the `GROUP BY orders.id, customers.name` result is not what you want?

Comment: simplly use `LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id `

Comment: @jarlh Ah Ok, thanks. I thought group by on two fields would have grouped by some kind of composite key. Does it just means: group by orders.id FIRST, THEN customers.name?

Comment: @YagamiLight No it's the same problem, I still have to aggregate.

Comment: Usually you can simply group by all selected columns that are not arguments to set functions!

Comment: @jarlh Thank you! You can answer with your comment and I will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add customers.name to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT orders.id, customers.name, COUNT(order_product.id)
FROM orders
INNER JOIN order_product ON orders.id = order_product.order_id
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
GROUP BY orders.id, customers.name
```

Usually you can simply group by all selected columns that are not arguments to set functions!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use window functions

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.id, customers.name, COUNT(order_product.id) OVER ( PARTITION BY orders.id)
FROM orders
INNER JOIN products ON orders.id = order_product.order_id
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id;
```